# Integral domain - Embedding

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain and the homomorphism
\begin{align}
\phi\colon \mathbb{Z} &\rightarrow R \\
n &\mapsto n \cdot 1_R
\end{align}

What does it mean that if $\ker \phi =\{0\}$ then $\phi$ is an embedding ($\operatorname{char}R=0$) and if $\ker \phi \neq \{0\}$ then $\phi$ is not an embedding?

Also why does it stand that if $\operatorname{char}R =p$ ($p$: prime) then there is an embedding
\begin{align}
\widetilde{\phi}: \mathbb{Z}_p &\hookrightarrow R \\
\overline{a} &\mapsto a \cdot 1_R
\end{align}
?

Comment: Embedding = injective homomorphism, and for a (ring, group) homomorphism, being injective is the same as having $\;\ker = 0\;$

Comment: When you say $n\cdot 1_R$ do you mean $1_R+\stackrel{(n)}{\cdots}+1_R$?

Comment: @GPerez Yes, that is what I mean...

Comment: @Timbuc Ok... I see... Thanks for the explanation!!!

Comment: Then $\mathrm{char} R = 0$ means the only amount of $1_R$s you can sum to get $0_R$ is $0$ (not any), which is exactly what happens if $\ker \phi= \{0\}$, which in turn makes the map an embedding.

Comment: In the case that the kernel isn't trivial, it has to be $(p)=p\mathbb Z$, for a prime $p$. Then just check if the second homomorphism you describe is well-defined and injective, or use an appropriate isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @GPerez We have that; If $charR=p$ then $Im \phi \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$. Do we use this to show the second embedding??

Comment: I added an answer, see if it answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

Embedding here means injective. For the second part, it is just the map induced by $\phi$ on the quotient (by the universal property of the quotient ring), which is injective as you mod out by the kernel.

Comment: I haven't understood the second part yet... Do you mean that that we use the fact that: If $charR=p$ then $Im \phi \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ ??

Answer (score 0):

If $\ker\phi \neq {0}$, then there exists $m\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\stackrel{(m)}{1_R+\cdots + 1_R} = 0$. A bit of reasoning shows that the smallest such $m$ must be prime. Call it $p$, and we now have $\ker\phi = p\mathbb Z$ (because we chose the smallest $p$, and $\mathbb Z$ is PID). Therefore, we have $$\mathbb Z/\ker\phi = \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \simeq \mathrm{Im}\phi$$

Which is given by $\tilde a\mapsto \stackrel{(a)}{1_R+\cdots + 1_R}$ (easy to verify). Compose with the inclusion $$\mathrm{Im}\phi\hookrightarrow R \atop x\mapsto x$$

to get an injective homomorphism, otherwise known as an embedding: $$\widetilde{\phi}: \mathbb{Z}_p \hookrightarrow R$$